# Regex: Replace content inside parenthesis of subquery in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I wish to replace the a subquery to the table name inside the subquery using regex in node.js.

e.g. converting the following query:

```
SELECT col1
FROM (SELECT col1::DECIMAL(10),
col2,
FROM @table_name)
WHERE (COND1) AND (COND2)
```

To:

```
SELECT col1
FROM @table_name
WHERE (COND1) AND (COND2)
```

I have tried using:

`string.replace(/\([^()]*\)/g, '')`
But it eliminates the entire content.

Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following regex replacement:

```js
var sql = `SELECT col1
FROM (SELECT col1,
col2,
FROM @table_name)
WHERE (COND1) AND (COND2)`;

sql = sql.replace(/\([^)]*\bFROM (@[^)]+)[^)]*\)/, "$1");
console.log(sql);
```

But to cover all possible edge cases, you might want to use a SQL parser.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Im using redshift, hence I cant use the parser. 
I updated my question since I have the type of the column in the query which consists of another parenthesis. I have tried using double negate lookahead (?!.*\),)